# Error while loading drm amdgpu : "ERROR - Unknown firmware load type" amdgpu_ucode_get_load_type -

Tags: gpu-driver, amdgpu, microcode

Recently, I have upgraded to linux 4.17-rc2 kernel to get bluetooth support in my HP 15 laptop with Intel core i5 7th gen processor. So, from few days, I am seeing this error message while booting Ubuntu:

**drm:amdgpu_ucode_get_load_type [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Unknown firmware load type**

Is this something to worry about? As I understand, this is DRI module and amdpgu ucode (microcode) loading. When I checked the log, it seems everything is loading fine, including switcheroo (hybrid graphics). But, this error message showing ucode?

```
] amdgpu 0000:01:00.0: enabling device (0400 -> 0403)
[    1.946708] [drm:amdgpu_ucode_get_load_type [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Unknown firmware load type
[    1.965186] amdgpu 0000:01:00.0: VRAM: 2048M 0x000000F400000000 - 0x000000F47FFFFFFF (2048M used)
[    1.965187] amdgpu 0000:01:00.0: GTT: 256M 0x0000000000000000 - 0x000000000FFFFFFF
[    1.965191] [drm] Detected VRAM RAM=2048M, BAR=256M
[    1.965192] [drm] RAM width 64bits DDR3
[    1.965249] [drm] amdgpu: 2048M of VRAM memory ready
[    1.965250] [drm] amdgpu: 3072M of GTT memory ready.
[    1.965958] amdgpu 0000:01:00.0: PCIE GART of 256M enabled (table at 0x000000F400040000).
[    1.966013] [drm] Supports vblank timestamp caching Rev 2 (21.10.2013).
[    1.966013] [drm] Driver supports precise vblank timestamp query.
[    1.966081] [drm] amdgpu: dpm initialized
```

Answer (score 0):

The message may be treated as a warning only, as it loads the firmware and driver. This is fixed in the patch: https://patchwork.freedesktop.org/patch/246240/

https://www.phoronix.com/forums/forum/linux-graphics-x-org-drivers/open-source-amd-linux/989248-rebranded-gcn-1-0-amd-radeon-520-dgp-in-my-hp-laptop-supported-in-amdgpu?p=1043896#post1043896